# React native sqlite how to render data (type JSON) from database on Flatlist?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Can anyone help me? My database has more field like this one:

```
[
  {
    "key":"word_1",
    "Word":"a",
    "Meaning":"a"
  },
  ...
]
```

I already read it from database but how can I store it to state and render each element on Flatlist.

Here is way i get data from Database:

```
    db.transaction(tx => {
      var sql =
        "SELECT * FROM tblVietAnh WHERE word LIKE '" +
        this.state._inputValue.toLowerCase() +
        "%' LIMIT 5";
      tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, results) => {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        setState({ _records: results.row.item });
        console.log(this.state._records);
        for (let i = 0; i  {
            _records: prevState._records.push(row.id, row.word, row.meaning);
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

But by this way i just have an array with separate row. So I cant access to each element. How can I fix this ?

Thank you!

Comment: The value you received from database is an array of objects that you have displayed?

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question, showing how you read it from the database and what you have tried so far.